# Facebook review process

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I have a staging and a production app and an app on Facebook which has a test version (staging). I need to add a new permission which requires that I submit it for review. However, I don't want to push this code to production as it will not work for users unless reviewed. However, it cannot be reviewed unless an API request is made from production using this new permission (it's currently only on staging).

I could change the API keys on my staging environment to the production ones which could solve this issue. However, does this mean that once I submit the app for review, no one will be able to use the production app until the review has finished?

Comment: Submitting new permissions for review does not affect the permissions that you had already reviewed earlier.